# Problem with installation SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019

I got a problem when I wanted to install SQL Server 2019. I don't have Setup Bootstrap on this path, I only have folders SSEI and License Terms on this path.

Windows Installer log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191105_001048\msoledbsql_Cpu64_1.log

I don't know why I don't have Setup Bootstrap on that path, it is the first time I'm installing SQL Server 2019.

The error:

[image: problem]

Comment: I would probably send a tweet to MS about this. GA just dropped today.

Comment: Setup bootstrap is created by the installer, do you have perms to create the folder?

Comment: So far both folders you see are created as first steps during installation after all I know. I suggest to check your harddrive via Explorer - right click your C-drive -> Properties / Tools / Check Now ...